NTP servers and DNS ordering
I have a main network with three main servers (call them A, B, and C).  They are all routers, 3 of 4 of my (serving) NTP servers, and 2 of 5 of my DNS servers.  The DNS servers (bind9) are all configured using sortlist to return, on each subnet, first the addresses on the subnet, then the addresses on the main network, and then other addresses; and this works.
The problem arises in the NTP servers on hosts on the peripheral networks.  For some reason, a server connected to B's network will attempt to talk to C on its routed network address,  not on its main network address (and vice versa).  Even stranger, they do not do the same with A.  It only does this on IPv6, as if I add -4 to the server line, it works as expected.  (It seems to prefer IPv6 over IPv4, and I consider this reasonable.)
So the question is, is there some magic to make ntpd honor the DNS server's ordering on IPv6?
# ntpd -version
ntpd 4.2.8p15@1.3728-o Wed Sep 23 11:46:38 UTC 2020 (1)


Can you clarify whether by "on its routed network address" you mean the source address selection, or the target address?  If the former, there are probably a few IPv6 source selection gremlins which might necessitate binding ntpd to particular interfaces (although doing this for only source addresses isn't really great).

@PaulGear  A, B, and C are routers.  Each has an address on the main network, and on other networks.  By "routed network address", I mean the one not on the main network.   In the first case I found, xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:3:yyyy:yyyy:yyyy:yyyy, instead of talking to xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:1::1 on the main network, used xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:2::1, despite the former being first in the DNS sort order.

That's not the way NTP was designed to work.  If you give it a list of four NTP servers, it can and should contact them all, and this is actually the only way for it to get fully accurate time.  (Otherwise it gets just one peer's view of the time, which is never the full picture.)
Learn more about this in the NTP best practice RFC: https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8633#section-3.2
You should give your NTP servers a list of fully contactable peers.

I give it 4 server lines.  Each name has 4 or 6 IP addresses for that host.  The lists are ordered.  How do I get it to go to the closer address?  It should not contact any given host more than once.

Hi @DavidG., this would be a lot easier with your actual config and DNS entries, but essentially if you want it to only contact hosts on your preferred addresses, you should give it DNS names which only include those addresses.

For example, if you give ntpd a line like server pool.my.domain.name and a DNS lookup of pool.my.domain.name includes the addresses 192.168.0.1, 192.168.1.1, 192.168.2.1, and 192.168.3.1, it has no way of knowing that they are all the same host, and will contact each address.  That's the way it was designed to work, and if they are routers, then it shouldn't actually make any difference which of those it contacts.

I've considered both.  I don't want to give my specific addresses in a public forum.  I have considered listing only preferred addresses in DNS, or in NTP configuration, but I also want to use a uniform configuration on all the hosts.

If you have 4 NTP hosts and each has 4 addresses, you would probably be better off creating a DNS entry for each host, which includes all that host's addresses, and then let ntpd work out which address provides the best response by using the pool directive.  It will start off by contacting all the addresses, but will eventually prune excess hosts until it arrives at the optimum configuration.

I think you are under a misunderstanding of server and pool.  With server, ntpd picks ONE address and uses it.  With pool, ntpd connects to all the addresses.  The term pool started being used before the pool command was added.

Have you actually watched what ntpd does over time with pool entries?

One of the strangest things I've noticed:   When I ping all 6 addresses of a host using noping, the performance improves as it goes down the list, whichever way I order the list.  It's as if the pathway gets worn open.

It seems to me to make and keep all addressed entries.  And this seems to match some documentation I've seen on ntppool.org.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

As I realized during the chat:  1) ntpd uses getaddrinfo() 2) getaddrinfo() reverses the order of the IPv6 addresses.
